# Mapping over list of dates in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

My function `fnc` returns as Image but on using the `ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(fnc))`, it returns an error `ImageCollection (Error)
ImageCollection.fromImages: Attempt to create an ImageCollection with non-image elements.`
 in the code below.

```js
var Date_Start = ee.Date('2015-05-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2017-12-01');
var Date_window = ee.Number(30);

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'month').round();
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0,n_months,1);
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'month')
}
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);

var fnc = function(d1) {
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(1,'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
  var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))

  return(S1.first())
}

var mt = ee.ImageCollection(dates.map(fnc));
print(mt)
```

How can I get the image collection back from the mapped function?

**EDIT**
After trying further, I am now getting a similar error while mosaicing two images (this time from Landsat 5) and then returning the mosaic. Code is below:

```
var p1 = ee.Geometry.Point([103.521,13.028]);
var p2 = ee.Geometry.Point([105.622,13.050]);

var Date_Start = ee.Date('2000-05-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2007-12-01');
var Date_window = ee.Number(30);

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'month').round();
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0,n_months,1);
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'month');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);
var fnc = function(d1) {
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(14,'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
  var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_TOA') 
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .filterBounds(p1).first()

  var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_TOA')
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .filterBounds(p2).first()

  var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image(S1), ee.Image(S2)]).mosaic();
  var image = mosaic.clip(TSL);


  return mosaic
};

var list_of_images = dates.map(fnc);
print('list_of_images', list_of_images);
var mt = ee.ImageCollection(list_of_images);
print(mt);
Map.addLayer(mt, {}, 'mt');
```

ERROR:
        List (Error)
        ImageCollection.fromImages: Attempt to create an ImageCollection with non-image elements.

Comment: If it complains about non-image elements, you probably have non-image elements...can you the give sample output of the function? (console.log it). Also make sure your function is correct. The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_creating) say you should use `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

> ImageCollection.fromImages: Attempt to create an ImageCollection with non-image elements.

will occur if you are attempting to create an image collection from a list of null objects. In your code, this will occur if you attempt to take the `.first()` element of an empty month-filtered S1 collection. The following code demonstrates this, by filtering the monthly collections to a region in the ocean where no Sentinel-1 images have been collected:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-136.14, 35.17]);
var Date_Start = ee.Date('2015-05-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2017-12-01');
var Date_window = ee.Number(30);

// Create list of dates for time series
var n_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'month').round();
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0,n_months,1);
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'month');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);

var fnc = function(d1) {
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(1,'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
  var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filterBounds(geometry);
  return(S1.first());
};

var list_of_images = dates.map(fnc);
print('list_of_images', list_of_images);
var mt = ee.ImageCollection(list_of_images);
print(mt);
Map.addLayer(mt, {}, 'mt');
```

If you instead you modify the filters so that at least one of the monthly collections has an image, the error will be avoided and your object `mt` will be a valid image collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tyler. That partially solved the issue. However, on further coding, the same error is showing up when I use 2 Landsat images and return a mosaic of them. I checked that the individual images are not `null`.The code is in the edited question above. Thanks.

Comment: Your second code listing is quite different... different image characteristics, includes cloud masking, uses a mosaic reducer, etc.  How about starting a new question that describes the bigger picture issue you are trying to solve? Something along the lines of: "How do you generate a collection of Landsat cloud-masked monthly composites?" or whatever question best describes the goal of your second code listing.

Comment: Ok, I have posted a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269449/how-to-generate-a-collection-of-mosaic-images-by-mapping-over-date-list-in-googl). Hope to get a solution soon. Thanks for your suggestion.